# Files and strings

Tags: c, file

I need to make a program in which the user chooses a continent. The program will read the file of the chosen continent. Then, the program will ask the capital of a country of the chosen continent. Right now, I'm focused on Europe. (The file is in Spanish, but is fine)

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/7e31966c2196455d4fd2aef1d74226e2.png]

The first line is the Country and the second line the capital and so on. I'm not very good at this. Surely it's a stupid mistake or I have misunderstood the theory. The code is executed but reads the file in a strange way. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 33
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N]);
//int Asia();
FILE *eu;
FILE *as;

int main()
{
    int p1, salir;
    char EuropaP[N][N];
    char EuropaC[N][N];
    while(salir != 0)
    {
        printf("-----MENU PRINCIPAL-----\n"); //main menu where the users selects the continent.
        printf("Elige un continente\n\n");
        printf("1. Europa\n");
        printf("2. Asia\n");
        printf("\nEscribe 0 para salir");
        printf("\nSeleccion: ");
        scanf("%d", &p1);
        if (p1 == 1)
        {
            Europa(EuropaP, EuropaC);
        }
        else if (p1 == 2)
        {
            //Asia();
        }
        else
            fclose(eu);
            //fclose(as);
        break;

    }
    return 0;
}
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N])
{
    int vida, c, i;
    eu = fopen("Europa.txt", "r");
    if (eu == NULL){
        printf("No se ha abierto correctamente el fichero");
    }
    else
        for(i=0; i<33; i++)
        {
            fscanf(eu, "%s\n%s", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
        }
    for(c=0; c<33; c++)
    {
        printf("%s\n%s", EuropaP[c], EuropaC[c]);
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Example of execution:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UUR5kxl.png]

As you can see the file is not being read correctly. I don't know how to copy the countries and capitals to the array.

PROBLEM FIXED! 
I added return 0; over here:

```
if (eu == NULL){
    printf("No se ha abierto correctamente el fichero");
    return 0;
}
```

changed the directory of the .txt file:

```
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N])
{
    int vida, c, i;
    eu = fopen("/Users/****/Desktop/Europa.txt", "r");
```

and finally, I'm using fgets instead of fscanf.

```
else
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        fgets(EuropaP[i], N, eu);
        fgets(EuropaC[i], N, eu);
    }
for(c=0; c<N; c++)
 printf("%s\n%s", EuropaP[c], EuropaC[c]);
    printf("\n");
```

Example of execution
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/d009ed7d36ef47d067dc9d4af806e077.png]

Comment: `%s` only reads one word. Some of the country names have more than one word.

Comment: You should use `fgets()` to read lines, not `fscanf()`.

Comment: Don't hard-code 33 in the function, use `i < N`

Comment: @user3121023 I've added the return 0 and now the execution doesn't print that weird thing. Now, the file is not opening I will add the directory of the file directly into the code.

Comment: @user3121023 File is opening now! Thank you!

Comment: Also check return values of all file IO, as well as all read functions, as well as all scanf functions (so this is triply important when reading a file with fscanf).

Comment: I'm using fgets now and It looks like working correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @Diego_ht Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum. Do not edit the title of your question to insert stuff like [solved] etc. Read the [faq]. Also, do _not_ edit your *question* to insert an *answer* into it!

Comment: Im sorry @dandan78, I just wanted to make things as clear as posible

Answer (score 1):

For lines with spaces, `fgets` would work. The newline can be removed using `strcspn`.

```
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N])
{
    int vida, c, i;
    eu = fopen("Europa.txt", "r");
    if (eu == NULL){
        printf("No se ha abierto correctamente el fichero");
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<33; i++)
    {
        if ( ! fgets ( EuropaP[i], N, eu)) {
            printf ( "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
        EuropaP[i][strcspn ( EuropaP[i], "\r\n")] = 0;//remove newline

        if ( ! fgets ( EuropaC[i], N, eu)) {
            printf ( "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
        EuropaC[i][strcspn ( EuropaC[i], "\r\n")] = 0;//remove newline

        printf("%s\n%s\n", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Iterate through the string and when a newline or carriage return is found, set a zero to terminate the string.

```
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N])
{
    int vida, c, i;
    int each = 0;
    eu = fopen("Europa.txt", "r");
    if (eu == NULL){
        printf("No se ha abierto correctamente el fichero");
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<33; i++)
    {
        if ( ! fgets ( EuropaP[i], N, eu)) {
            printf ( "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
        each = 0;
        while ( EuropaP[i][each]) {
            if ( '\r' == EuropaP[i][each] || '\n' == EuropaP[i][each]) {
                EuropaP[i][each] = 0;
                break;
            }
            each++;
        }

        if ( ! fgets ( EuropaC[i], N, eu)) {
            printf ( "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        } 
        each = 0;
        while ( EuropaC[i][each]) {
            if ( '\r' == EuropaC[i][each] || '\n' == EuropaC[i][each]) {
                EuropaC[i][each] = 0;
                break;
            }
            each++;
        }

        printf("%s\n%s\n", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work the thing is that I'm not allowed to use strcspn :(